# How to edit Livecode Github source?

Tags: git, github, livecode

I noticed a very simple bug on Livecode IDE, and I tried to open the source file on GitHub. Unfortunately source files like /ide/toolset/*.rev  are main Livecode components: so trying to open one them I  obtain a substitution of the current Livecode enviroment.

How do you act on Livecode sources?

Comment: I'd like to edit /ide/Toolset/revmenubar.rev

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to edit them directly on GitHub because they are binary files (LiveCode stackFiles). Which means they are hopeless for version control. Which in turn means that RunRev aren't accepting pull requests on the IDE at the moment. They accept them only on the engine for the time being.

That being said you can edit the IDE stackFiles really easily by choosing View > LiveCode UI Elements in Lists from the menubar then you will see all the IDE stacks in the project browser so you can edit and save them. Generally if I want to contribute to the IDE I will open a bug report with a detailed description of the code that needs to change so that someone on the IDE team can do it.

FYI I have a project here (http://github.com/montegoulding/lcVCS) that helps with version control that I hope one day RunRev will use on the IDE so we can send them pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can edit them directly in the GitHub web interface; you could fork the repo, make the changes locally on you PC and then submit a pull request with the fixes.